# Angle made by bullet in a different frame of reference

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, relative-motion

I did solve this question, though I did not understand it completely due to the flow of the same type of questions, its language, and one other thing bugged me which I will be stating after the question statement.

> **Question Statement:-**
>   An armoured car $2$ m long and $3$ m wide is moving at $13$ m/s when a bullet hits it in a direction making an angle of $\tan^{-1}{\dfrac{3}{4}}$ with the car as seen from the street. The bullet enters the car at one corner and passes out at the diagonally opposite corner. Neglecting any interaction between bullet and the car, find the time for the bullet to cross the car.

---

**My doubts:-** What does the question mean by "as seen from the street"? Which reference frame does it mean? I thought that it was referring to the Earth's reference frame, but if so, it still leaves me with one more doubt. Which angle does it refer to? Is it the one above the diagonal or the one below it? I think that there can be two angles at which the bullet can enter the car - one at $\tan^{-1}{3/4}$ with the vertical and other at the same angle with the horizontal. In both the cases the answer comes out to be different, but the book only presents one answer, which is according to the figure below.

Am I correct? If not, where did I go wrong?

[image: bullet and car]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path of the bullet makes an angle of atan(3/4) relative to the road.

The armoured car is a rectangle.  It is in 2 different positions on the road when the bullet (1) enters through the lower left corner, and (2) leaves through the upper right corner.

It is not clear to me if the car is 3m tall or 2m tall.

Comment: According to what I understood of the question it seems the width is refereed to that length which the car has across the road and the length that it says to be $2m$ is along the road.

Comment: If that is the case then the height of the car is not given. Since only 2 lengths are given, I think one must be horizontal and the other vertical, with the car seen side-on as a rectangle. But I agree with you that "long" and "wide" usually refer to horizontal dimensions.... Another possibility is that the car and bullet are viewed from above - or below!

Comment: I also was confused about that but after some thought I came to the conclusion that as we are only given two dimensions of hte car then it must be referring to the above view of the car.